# JSP/MySQL how to stop a form from accepting entries if a value in a column in mysql is filled

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

this is my first time ever writing here, Idk if the way I asked is clear...

I have a form with a select with 4 options. These 4 options are saved in a database in MySQL in a single column. I want to count the amount for all of these 4 options and stop when a certain max is reached.

Ex. Option 1 in my select is "Event A", which can hold 100 people
Option 2 is "Event B", which can hold 200 people
Option 3 is "Event C", which can hold 150
Option 4 is "Event D", which can hold 100

All these, Event A, Event B, Event C and Event D are in a big "Events" column in MySQL. How to make it so the form stops accepting entries if Event A is filled?

Comment: Have you looked into adding validation into your controller?